# Sharing variables between page and background task

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a pretty long task for my page, so I'm running it in a background task since I don't want it to block any postback events. Let's just assume this code looks something like this

```
Task task = new Task(() =>
{
    for (;;)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        var x = (int)ViewState["progress"];
        x++;
        ViewState["progress"] = x;
    }
});

task.Start();
```

As you can see, I'm storing the code in the `ViewState`. I have a progress bar on the page along with a timer that ticks every 5 seconds to perform a postback event. In this event, I'm updating the progress bar. The code looks something like this.

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int perc = (int)ViewState["progress"];

    //Progress bar code here
}
```

The progress bar wasn't updating so I tried debugging and for some reason, I'm getting entirely different values in both the cases. The timer's event gives me 0 all the time but it seems to be increasing in the loop. It's like there are two different instances of the ViewState

I've also tried locking the ViewState or using the global variable instead, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a recipe for disaster. `Thead.Sleep` will suspend the thread which is very undesirable.

**Disclaimer I do not recommend this technique!**

You might consider using the slightly better

```
task = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    for (var progress = 0; progress < 100; ++progress)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        ViewState[nameof(progress)] = progress;
    }
});
```

That said, it is still a recipe for disaster.

Comment: What exactly makes it a recipe for disaster?

Either way, what I wanna know is why the values I'm getting are different.

Comment: Asynchronous operations across multiple threads mutating a global variable stored in session state?

Comment: I can't think of a better way to update the progress bar. Keeping the entire operation synchronous blocks the UI from updating.

Comment: Shouldn't the progress be updated based on work that is being performed? Why not await a task that performs the work and update the progress when it returns.

Comment: Like if you have 20 batches of  work, `var tasks = batches.Select(batch => Task.Run(async ()=> await ProcessAsync(batch))).ToList(); while(tasks.Any()) { var completed = await Task.WhenAny(batch); tasks.Remove(completed); ++progress; }`

Comment: @Kash Or you can use some polling method to read the status or websockets using [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr)

Comment: @SignalR a much better idea.

Comment: I am indeed planning to update it based on the work being done. I added the loop in my post so I could just show how I'm changing the value of the progress bar. But the UI won't update as long as there is a postback, which is why I added the timer. And the button click event that performs the main task ends up blocking any other postback events (including the timer's tick event). It's why I'm performing the task in the background. That way it'll continue running even after the button click event is done and won't block anything. Got any better solutions?

Comment: Please do not use `Thread.Sleep`, it blocks the whole thread. Also, by using async, you get the advantage of default continue on captured context behavior which I think may matter a lot here, but my .aspx is not strong.

Comment: @jjchiw I'll have to look into that

Comment: @AluanHaddad but if you use async, does the task continue running in the background even when the method is finished?

Comment: Yes, you would need to tell it when to stop. I will add a cieling

Comment: Alright. But do you know why I might be getting different values in the viewstate on both the threads? I also tried using a global variable instead and it's the same case

Comment: @Kash sorry, my expertise with ASPX constructs like ViewState is very limited.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I actually just figured it out. But thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. You should post your solution.